# Constructor takes only ID of referenced entity, but getter returns the entity itself - possible?

Tags: spring, hibernate, kotlin, jpa

Let's assume, I've a simple relationship of `Student` and `Teacher` Entities

I'm using Spring Boot with kotlin-jpa plugin, so data classes should work fine:

```kotlin
data class Student(
   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
   val id: Long = null,
 
   @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
   var responsibleTeacher: Teacher,
   // ... other props
)

data class Teacher(
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
    val id: Long = null,
    
    val name: String,
    // ... other props
)
```

My problem: To construct an instance of `Student`, I always need an instance of the (already persisted) `Teacher` as well. As I only have the `ID` of the teacher at hand, I first need to obtain the full `Teacher` entity from the database and then pass it to the constructor of `Student`:

```kotlin
val responsibleTeacher = getTeacherFromDB(teacherId)
val student = Student(responsibleTeacher)
```

What I would like to to, is to pass only the `Teacher` ID in the constructor, but still being able to query the full `Teacher` entity from `Student` when calling the getter/property.

```kotlin
data class Student(
   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
   val id: Long = null,
   
   @Column(name = "responsible_teacher_id")
   private var responsibleTeacherId: Long,
   
    // ... other props

    // pseudo-code, doesn't work!
    // Should query the [Teacher] Entity by [responsibleTeacherId], specified in constructor
   @OneToOne(fetch = LAZY)
   var responsibleTeacher:Teacher
)
```

I was messing around with this for almost a day but couldn't find any working solution. Is there any?

Answer (score 2):

For this purpose you can use a proxy that you can retrieve by calling `entityManager.getReference(Teacher.class, teacherId)`

Answer (score 0):

Use `@JoinColumn` annotation

```
   @Column(name = "responsible_teacher_id")
   private var responsibleTeacherId: Long,
   
   @JoinColumn(name = "responsible_teacher_id")
   @OneToOne(fetch = LAZY, insertable = false, updatable = false)
   var responsibleTeacher: Teacher
```